# Using WeakMap for HTMLElement in DOM

Tags: javascript

I want observe for my list HTMLElements, so I use WeakMap.

Code for example:

```js
let weakList = new WeakMap(), /// Empty
    element = $0; /// $0 for selection any element on document's page

weakList.set(element, true);
console.log(weakList); /// Not empty

element.remove();
element = null;
console.log(weakList); /// Not empty
```

I don't understand what is happens.

Comment: Why are you using WeakMap instead of Map? Also, a Map is not a “list”. A WeakMap is not a live view of the DOM.

Comment: When an element is removed from the DOM it doesn’t invalidate weak-references immediately. You’ll have to wait for the next GC.

Comment: @Dai because I want to work with conveniently list of DOM elements, and it's economy memory.

Comment: A WeakMap won’t save you any memory in the context you’ve posted.

Comment: @Dai so how I can observe valid DOM nodes, that is exist in document?

Comment: What do you mean by "observe"? What are you **really** wanting to accomplish? Are you familiar with the DOM `MutationObserver`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver